# Fork GitHub repository for personal use and contributions

Tags: git, github

I am somewhat new to contributing to GitHub so I am wondering on the proper way to do this.

So I downloaded an existing repository and created my repo based on it. Because I only took a part of the initial repository; changed the whole file structure to meet my setup and started changing/developing it for my own use I didn't fork it but instead just cloned it and changed the remote to my repo.

Later I have found myself wanting to submit PRs to the initial repo to help the original developer with parts of the code that I improved that I considered to be generic enough to be of use in the initial repo. In order to be able to submit PRs I have forked the repo.

SO right now I have 2 repositories on my GitHub and 2 different location on my system - 1 is my repo that is slowly deviating from the source and another that is a direct copy of it existing only for the purposes of contributing to the original project.

I am wondering if there is a correct way to approach such a situation and maybe not have 2 repos from my side of things? Also only my secondary repo has a fork link to the original project while I would rather have my main one redirecting to the source.

Thanks and I hope I explained the it clearly enough.

Comment: You could add in one of the repository (preferably the forked one otherwise you won't be able to create pull request) a remote pointing toward the other repo (a local from disk or the one hosted on GitHub) and then `fetch`. You will have all in this repo. Then clean and sync as you can...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the original repository in GitHub was `orig/repo`, and your forked repository is `user/repo`. Let the clone of the original in your local system by be `A` and the clone of the fork be `B`. Let the copy of `A` stored on GitHub be at `user/A`.

From your description, you have been working on changes in `A`, while `B` contains the original code in `user/repo`, and has since then remained unchanged. You wish to keep only one local copy, while having the option to contribute back to `orig/repo`.

The way to do this would be to push your changes to a branch in `user/repo`, and then open a pull request to `orig/repo`. So, you need to add a remote for `A` to `user/repo`.

This can be done using:

```sh
git remote add <remote-name> https://github.com/user/repo
```

where `<remote-name>` is an identifier for your new remote.

Subsequently, to push (similarly pull, fetch, etc.) branch `b` to `user/repo`, you can use:

```sh
git push <remote-name> b
```

In such a fashion, you can maintain separate branches for your own changes and for changes that you wish to contribute back, in the same repository. This also makes it easier to merge branches or cherry pick changes from one branch to another as required.

Comment: So let me see if I got it right.
I will have 1 repository on my github account that is fork of the original one and will have 2 branches.
`Master` for my own version that I am customising for myself
and `Giving-Back` that will mirror the original repo
This way I could have one version stored locally as well and just switch branches when I want to contribute back?

Comment: Yes, assuming your customizations and contributions are not completely independent of each other.